# How to animate in a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a list like Pinterest using `UICollectionView` that has cell animation similar to Google Plus's list.

For `UITableView`, I can do cell animation in this call back

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

But `UICollectionViewDelegate` have no such the callback.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all of the animation you'll want to do should be handled by your UICollectionViewLayout subclass. UICollectionViews are pretty awesome, and can probably handle what you want to do very nicely.

Describe the animation you want to do, add an image, or show the code. I'm too lazy to go download apps to answer questions.